# How do I find out the last object in a sliced ​queryset list at django?

Tags: python, django

How do I find out the last object in a sliced ​​queryset list at django?
Even if I use last() and first() in the queryset list, the following error occurs.

```
Cannot reverse a query once a slice has been taken.
```

I created a queryset list by putting the condition as below.

```py
comment = Comment.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,parent=None).order_by('-created_at')[:10]
```

and here is comment

```
<QuerySet [<Comments: Comments object (149)>, <Comments: Comments object (148)>, <Comments: Comments object (147)>, <Comments: Comments object (146)>, <Comments: Comments object (145)>, <Comments: Comments object (144)>, <Comments: Comments object (143)>, <Comments: Comments object (142)>, <Comments: Comments object (141)>, <Comments: Comments object (140)>]>
```

i want to get <Comments: Comments object (140)>
How do I find out the last object in a sliced ​​queryset list at django?

Comment: You can not call `.last()` on a sliced queryset, so `[:10]`, you thus should remove the `[:10]` part.

Comment: use `.last()` in the objects..

Comment: `list(comment)[-1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option is to convert your queryset to a list and perform a negative indexing on it:

```
last_on_page = list(Comment.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,parent=None).order_by('-created_at')[:10])[-1]
```

The drawback of this solution is: you have to check if the queryset returns something at all, as accessing the `-1` element on an empty list will fail. It also executes the whole queryset, which can have a negative impact on the performance, especially if your slices are big or your model is complex.

2nd solution is to cleverly reverse the queryset or just calculate which element to fetch from the database. Unfortunately, this requires fetching the total count of items returned by your query, as Django doesn't support negative indexing (and if it did, it would perform the additional query to fetch the count anyway).

```
total_comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,parent=None)

# directly fetching a single element
last_on_page = Comment.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,parent=None).order_by('created_at')[9 if last_on_page > 10 else last_on_page - 1]

# getting the same slice as before, but reversed
comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,parent=None).order_by('created_at')[total_comments - 10 if total_comments > 10 else 0:]
# and getting the first element from the slice above, which should equal to the last element from the original slice:
last_on_page = comments[0]

# if you now want to iterate over the slice, you can do it in reverse, so you don't have to create a 2nd one.
```

Comment: I solved the problem this way. First of all, the sliced ​​queryset is absolutely necessary, so the first option solved the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

the `-1` index in python will grab the last item in a list (same for -2 as 2nd last)

```py
comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,parent=None).order_by('-created_at')[:10]

last_comment = comments[-1]
```

alternatively in django

```py
comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,parent=None).order_by('-created_at')[:10]

last_comment = comments.last()
```

Comment: Negative indexing doesn't work in Django querysets and `.last()` doesn't work with sliced queries.

Comment: negative indexing should work with the slice, if last() does not

Comment: `AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.` when trying to execute your first exaple. `TypeError: Cannot reverse a query once a slice has been taken.` for the 2nd one.

Comment: sorry, what about `comments[-1:]`?

Comment: Same thing. Negative indexing is not supported at all on Django querysets, as it would need to fetch the actual count of the elements to know how to assemble the final query, which will result in an implicit query to the database.

Comment: you may be able to render it to a new queryset like 
`Comment.objects.filter(id__in=comments.values_list('id', flat=True)).last()`

Comment: `last_comment = list(comments)[-1]`@Abdul_Aziz_Barkat showed